# Magento 2.2.0 - fails to add bundle product

Tags: magento2

I have tried to add product with bundle type that time getting error like below.

Could not save child: "Unknown entity type: Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection\Interceptor requested"

Answer (score -1):

i got same issues for this trouble, i resolved by add interface : Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\NoninterceptableInterface to 
Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection
the final class define look like:

class Selection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\NoninterceptableInterface

Comment: Where exactly did you add this? Any more info?

Answer (score -1):

Change

class Selection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel

to

class Selection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\NoninterceptableInterface

on below file

**vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/Selection.php**

Comment: You really shouldn't be editing core files. And editing something in the vendor directly will just get overwritten the next time that package is upgraded through composer. This is inappropriate for two reasons.